# how to destroy this tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter

Please, how can I destroy this tkinter window?

```
from Tkinter import *
import time

def win():
    root = Tk()

    root.wait_visibility(root)
    root.attributes('-alpha', 0.7)

    root.overrideredirect(True)
    root.configure(background='black')
    root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1) #zostane navrchu
    w = 200 # width for the Tk root
    h = 50 # height for the Tk root
    # get screen width and height
    ws = root.winfo_screenwidth() # width of the screen
    hs = root.winfo_screenheight() # height of the screen
    # calculate x and y coordinates for the Tk root window
    x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
    y = hs - h - 50 #(hs/2) - (h/2)

    lab = Label(root, text="Hello, world!")
    lab.pack()

    #x = 50
    #y = 50
    root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
    root.mainloop()

app = win()
app.destroy() #not working
```

Answer (score 1):

`app` has no method `destroy`, it is a `None` object since your function has no return value, you should place `root.destroy` inside a Button INSIDE the `win()` function. Such as:

```
import Tkinter
root = Tkinter.Tk()
button = Button(root, text="quit", command=root.destroy)
button.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

Using a class:

```
import Tkinter

class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tkinter.Tk()
        button = Tkinter.Button(self.root, text = 'root quit', command=self.quit)
        button.pack()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def quit(self):
        self.root.destroy()

app = App()
```

Comment: You are correct that win() does not return a value; however your suggested solution will not work either.  The function `mainloop` doesn't return until root.quit is called.

Comment: yes, you are right i was in the middle of editing it to show him how to put a button and set it to destroy, the link on my comment is that actually haha

Answer (score 1):

A tkinter program will not execute code after the `mainloop` call.  As the name implies, it's a loop, and the program remains inside that loop until the loop is terminated with a call to `root.quit.`  You need to construct an event-driven program and quit in response to a user action.  An example: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/minimal-app.html